# does selectpdf support finding string and replacing with pdf form fields into a pdf document?

Tags: selectpdf

I could not readily find an answer to this question. I'm using selectpdf to convert html to pdf and it's working well. at the same time, i have a need to take the generated pdf and selectively replace specific text with pdf form fields (for purposes of esignature) into the pdf document. I don't see anything obvious in the selectpdf object framework that allows creation of pdf form fields and/or performs "find" operations to find specific words or sequences or characters in the pdf. Is any of this  possible  ?

thanks